# How do I get my Flex app to scroll vertically when view in a browser?

Tags: html, css, flash, apache-flex, flash-builder

I have a web app built in Flash Builder 4.5. Its dimensions are 1150 x 900. When I try to view it on a smaller monitor or lower resolution, I can only scroll horizontally. I need it to scroll vertically. Is there a setting I am missing or could it be something else. I am not going to post any code at this time because I do not believe it is a syntax issue. If anyone feels I may be wrong, I will post the code needed. Thanks

http://dev.listgiants.com/Main.html is the site URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The height parameter in the HTML is set as 100%, should be a fixed size.

You have this:

```
 swfobject.embedSWF(
                "Main.swf", "flashContent", 
                "1150", "100%",
```

Should be something like this:

```
 swfobject.embedSWF(
                "Main.swf", "flashContent", 
                "1150", "900",
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple enough.  It's all about how you setup your SWFObject in your HTML.  From your actual HTML Source:

```
 swfobject.embedSWF(
                "Main.swf", "flashContent", 
                "1150", "100%", 
                swfVersionStr, xiSwfUrlStr, 
                flashvars, params, attributes);
```

You'll notice that you have your width set as an absolute and your height as a percentage.  You either need to set both to absolutes *or* set both to percentages and let Flex do the scrolling for you within a container.  Flex should automatically add scrollbars if the content of a container set to width/height 100%.

Comment: The width and height are declared in two other places in the html. `<noscript>
            <object classid="clsid:foo" width="1150" height="100%" id="Main">      <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="Main.swf" width="1150" height="100%">` Should those be set to a static number as well?

Answer (score 0):

you can specify it in style.In index.html file, within style declaration, paste following code,

```
html, body  {height:100%; width:100%; min-width:1024px; min-height:768px; overflow:auto; position:absolute;}
```

i hope it should also works.